# Get unique email contacts from Android contact provider

Tags: android, android-contacts

I would like to get all contacts have email id.
A row for every unique email.

Right now I have following implementation, but it will give email for every account, so have duplicate email contact rows.

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {    
final String[] PROJECTION = {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email._ID,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS
            };

            return new CursorLoader(
                    this,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                    ContactCursorAdapter.PROJECTION,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            );
}
```

Comment: Worst case scenario is that you will have to manually iterate over them

Comment: Are you displaying in a `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

_ID is unique for every email item in Data table.
Should use CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID in projection, that will help to get unique contact.

```
    @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {    

final String[] PROJECTION = {
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS
                };

                return new CursorLoader(
                        this,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                        PROJECTION,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
    }
```